# Org mode: Need to create date range with time interval and weekly repeat under a headline

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I want a series of appointments to include in the org-mode agenda.

I want the first occurrence of appointment to start from <2022-04-26 Tue 12:00-13:00> and ending occurrence on <2022-05-28 Tue 12:00-13:00>. I want this appointment to occur only on Tuesdays.

I tried the following but it doesn't seem to be working,

```
* My Appointment
    <2022-04-26 Tue 12:00-13:00 +1w>--<2022-06-28 Tue 12:00-13:00>
```

Is there any elegant way than putting all Tuesdays with timestamps from start till end dates or cloning the headline for N number of weeks with +1w jump?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you use the American date format (month-day-year):

`<%%(diary-cyclic 7 4 26 2022) 12:00-13:00>`

Comment: How is this better than `<2022-04-26 Tue 12:00-13:00 +1w>` ? The entry doesn't specify end date. For some reason `diary-cyclic` entry is not appearing in my agenda (although `diary-block` appears)